# $and expression must be a nonempty array

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to create a query with mgo lib.

```
q := bson.M{
    "$and": bson.M{
        "btId": neighbour.BtId,
        "timestamp": bson.M{
            "$gt": sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp,
            "$lt": sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp.Add(time.Second * 3000),
        },
    },
}
```

So this renders into `map[$and:map[btId:BTR0102 timestamp:map[$gt:2012-04-11 19:08:59 +0200 CEST $lt:2012-04-11 19:58:59 +0200 CEST]]]` but I get error `$and expression must be a nonempty array` when trying to execute the query

It should be : `btId = "123" AND timestamp > sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp AND timestamp < sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp + 3000s`

Thank you

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/). It's argument(s) is an "array" `[]`, and the BSON map you are suppliying is **not** an array. Nor do you acutally need to use the `$and` since **ALL** MongoDB query conditions are **altready** and "AND" condition unless explicitly stated otherwise ( i.e `"timestamp": { "$gt": data, "$lt": data }` is another way of writing an "AND". So simply remove the wrapping `"$and":: bson.M{ }` and just use the conditions directly as the keys of the map for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
q := bson.M{
    "btId": neighbour.BtId,
    "timestamp": bson.M{
        "$gt": sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp,
        "$lt": sensorDataStartPoint.Timestamp.Add(time.Second * 3000),
    },
}
```

It's unnecessary to use `$and` since that's the default for a MongoDB query.

Also note, if it was necessary to use an `$and` the parameters expected there are an array, not a map!